# running slattach on pseudo tty

Tags: linux, serial-port, ip, tty

I try to open a network connection through a pair of pseudo tty's on linux os.

```
# slattach -v /dev/ptmx
cslip started on /dev/ptmx interface sl0
```

OK, this was the "creating side" for the pseudo tty.

I can look in /dev/pts and find the new pty there.
If I now try to use slattach also on this side I got:

```
slattach -v /dev/pts/3
slattach: tty_open(/dev/pts/3, RW): Input/output error
```

I traced with strace:

```
28 5505  write(1, "slattach: tty_open: trying to op"..., 46) = 46
29 5505  open("/dev/pts/3", O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK) = -1 EIO (Input/output error)
30 5505  write(2, "slattach: tty_open(/dev/pts/3, R"..., 55) = 55
31 5505  exit_group(3)
```

All this happens on different distros of ubuntu, tested on 10.04 and 11.04, both are failing.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at the man page `pty(7)`.

Basically, /dev/ptmx uses the Unix 98 pseudo-terminal interface and requires that your program uses grantpt(3) and unlockpt(3). Here, slattach (the one that opens /dev/ptmx, not the other one) doesn't do so, and any program that tries to open the slave pseudo-terminal associated to the master will fail, as you experienced.

You can force slattach to do grantpt() and unlockpt() by overloading the open() call with an external
routine, [see this example](http://www.pmmh.espci.fr/~knguyen/comp/libwrapptmx.html)